# How does mail end up in /var/mail/<username>?

Tags: mail-transport-agent, mail-delivery-agent

I've found plenty of information about where the mail comes *from*; typically cron scripts, but also things like apt-listchanges.

I've found plenty of information about how to *read* the mail once it's there; use `mail` or `mutt` or simply use `less` on the file.

But I haven't managed to find any information about the bit in between, how the mail actually gets there. Presumably there's an MTA/MDA somewhere, but what it is, and how you configure it, I've drawn a blank. Every search I do just returns answers to the above two questions.

Comment: depending on the kind of Unix, there are several available. The granddaddy of them all is sendmail.

Comment: Yes, there's a MTA / MDA somewhere.  Cherish every moment you don't need to touch either.

Comment: Actually, the granddaddy of them all was `mail` in 1st Edition.  Sendmail came along with BSD.

Comment: In which case, I suppose my question becomes: how do I find out what MTA/MDA my system is using?

Comment: The answer depends on your OS.

Comment: In the particular case I'm looking at now, Debian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi, although I was hoping the answer as to how to find out wouldn't be too OS-specific...

Answer (score 2):

> how do I find out what MTA/MDA my system is using?

Use your system's package manager.  Look for packages for qmail, Postfix, exim, smail, ZMailer, MMDF, or Sendmail being installed.

There are a few less common packages.  You might have a very cut down system that passes everything along to a smarthost, such as mini-qmail or ssmtp for example.

Of course, sometimes this comes with the operating system and you do not need to look at your packages at all.  If you have FreeBSD, for example, you *will* have BSD Sendmail, because that is (still) part of the operating system and not an add-on package.

In a rare possibility, you might have a derivative of the old set-GID Unix `mail`, which was capable of delivering to mailboxes directly.

> how the mail actually gets there

- [the qmail pictures](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/pictures.html)
- [the qmail "big pictures"](http://www.nrg4u.com/)
- [ZMailer design summary](http://www.zmailer.org/zman/ztutorial.shtml#ZTUT-ZFEATURES-DESIGN-SUMMARY)
- [How MMDF works](http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/MailMsgG/mmdfN.back.html)
- [the Postfix architecture overview](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html)

An entire book could be written on this.  Several have been.  Really that's far too broad a subject for a Stack Exchange answer if it is not *at least* tied down to a specific software.

Comment: So, I think I'm still missing something here. Presumably, programs like cron aren't separately programmed to deal with every single MTA/MDA in existence, and there's a common interface that they use, or at least a small number of common interfaces. If so, what is that common interface?

Comment: @MarkRaymond Simplifying, messages can be injected either by SMTP, or by some kind of local injection agent. SMTP is [standardized](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2821.txt), but local injection agent are not, there are about as many of those as there are MTAs. They are not _fundamentally_ dissimilar, but they're far from identical. Which is why things need to be _configured_ to work together, and the way to configure them depends on the OS, and on what things you're trying to get to talk to each other. If you expect automagic configuration you'll be disappointed.